# Adding multiple Icomoon fonts to the website

Tags: css, svg, fonts, icons, webfonts

The dev company I hired to develop a mobile website failed to include selection.json file into the folder, and never even thought to keep it locally for themselves for future reference during the support period... Basically, all they did include were the font files: TTF, EOT, SVG, and WOFF.

Here's what Icomoon says about adding more glyphs to an existing font: *Each font pack you download from the IcoMoon app comes with a selection.json file which you can import back to the app in order to modify or update your font, along with the class names associated with its glyphs.*

Now I need to add more glyphs to the font. It looks like the simplest approach would be to generate another font, and add it to the style.css. Could you please advise how to do that? the original lines are:

```
@font-face {    
  font-family: 'icomoon';    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?t9csor');    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefixt9csor') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff?t9csor') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf?t9csor') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.svg?t9csor#icomoon') format('svg');    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"],    
[class*=" icon-"] {    
  speak: none;    
  line-height: 1;    
  font-style: normal;    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-variant: normal;    
  text-transform: none;    
  font-family: 'icomoon';}

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
```

Or, perhaps, there's another way to add icons to this font, without breaking its structure and having to revise entire CSS changing the class names throughout the website?

Thank you!

Comment: You ought to explain "section.json" as no one who is unfamiliar with icomoon will be able to understand it.

Comment: Edit your question to include what icomoon says rather than just posting it as a comment. People will read your question until they get lost at the selection.json part and then vote to close the question without reading all the comments.

Comment: ok, thanks for the tip. I'm new to it.

Comment: You're welcome. That's what reviewers are for :)

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to find all of the icons in your current icon font and create a new font using both the current icons as well as whatever new icons you want to include. You'll then replace the current font with the new one.

Another option is to create a new font that only includes your new icons, then include that in your website along with the existing icon font. Using the icomoon app, you can customize the font name and class prefix by clicking on "Preferences". I would recommend doing this in order to avoid conflicting with the current "icomoon" font included in your website.

[image]

If you want to include both your old font and the new font, you'll then include some CSS similar to this (generated by icomoon):

```
@font-face {    
  font-family: 'icomoon';    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?t9csor');    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.eot?#iefixt9csor') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.woff?t9csor') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf?t9csor') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/icomoon.svg?t9csor#icomoon') format('svg');    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {    
  font-family: 'ourotherfontname';    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/ourotherfontname.eot?t9csor');    
  src: url('../fonts/icomoon/ourotherfontname.eot?#iefixt9csor') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/ourotherfontname.woff?t9csor') format('woff'), url('../fonts/icomoon/ourotherfontname.ttf?t9csor') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/icomoon/ourotherfontname.svg?t9csor#ourotherfontname') format('svg');    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-style: normal;
}

[class^="icon-"],    
[class*=" icon-"],
[class^="anoterclassprefix-"],    
[class*="anotherclassprefix-"] {    
  speak: none;    
  line-height: 1;    
  font-style: normal;    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-variant: normal;    
  text-transform: none;    
  font-family: 'ourotherfontname';}

  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
```

Comment: Thank you Steve. The problem about the first option is that they used custom icons, not to be found on icomoon. And about the second, yes, i know icomoon provides a sample css, my question is how to use both fonts, how do i put them both in the CSS?

Comment: @Andy I believe you should be able to re-import the icons into icomoon using the .svg font file.

Comment: I am, but without the selection.json file all data, i.e. class names, glyph structure etc. will be lost. If i extend it with the new icons, and generate a new font, i'll have to revise the whole website to make sure new classes are in place, and being a CSS newbie, it's a tough job to do...

Comment: @Andy make sense. Your best bet is probably to just create an additional font and include that.

Comment: this is what i'm trying to figure out... As far as i understand the font-face rule needs to come at the top of the style.css file. If i use two, how do i put them? both rules first, then classes, i mean this stuff: '[class^="anoterclassprefix-"],    
[class*="anotherclassprefix-"] {    
  speak: none;    
  line-height: 1;    
  font-style: normal;    
  font-weight: normal;    
  font-variant: normal;    
  text-transform: none;    
  font-family: 'ourotherfontname';}' or two rules with additional data one after another?

Comment: @Andy I've edited my answer. Basically you'll include the font-face rules, then the CSS selectors for the icons.